# Google Prettify cutting my code- need fix

Tags: html, css, prettify, google-code-prettify

currently I have code that is being cut off at the < in the for loop because the browser treats it as a tag, does anyone have a fix for this?:

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
int count_simd(char *arr, int len, char key) {
    int count = 0;
    __m128i sixteenValues = _mm_setzero_si128();
    __m128i result = _mm_setzero_si128();
    __m128i keyV = _mm_set1_epi8(key);
    for(int j=0; j < len/16*16; j+=16){
    sixteenValues =_mm_load_si128((__m128i*)(arr+j)); 
    result = _mm_sub_epi8(result, _mm_cmpeq_epi8(sixteenValues, keyV));
    }
    for(int i=len/16*16; i<len; i++){
        if(arr[i]==key)
            count++;
    }
    char A[16];
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)A, result);
    for(int k=0; k<16; k++){
        count+=*(A+k);
    }
    return count;
}
</pre>
```

In the source of the rendered page, everything comes up right until:

```
<len; i++){="" if(arr[i]="=key)" count++;="" }="" char="" a[16];="" _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)a,="" result);="" for(int="" k="0;" k<16;="" k++){="" count+="*(A+k);" return="" count;="" <="" pre=""><span class="pln">
        </span></len;>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. Even inside a `<pre>` element, the `<`, `>`, and `&` characters must be encoded as `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks I completely forgot about this!